# Folder converted to branch?

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

In TFS (We are using 2012) why is the default to convert your source folder to a branch?
[image: Option]

I really don't consider the source a branch. What, if any, advantages/disadvantages does this have?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't consider the source a branch" the source folder by definition becomes a branch as soon as you create a branch from it. The target folder is also a branch which is a child of the source branch.

There are no disadvantages to enabling this. Regardless of whether you have this enabled or not the Source and Target will have a branching relationship and you will be able to merge changes between the 2 branches.

If you have this box enabled, as well as being able to merge between source and target you will also be able to use the branch visualisation tools in Visual Studio. These tools are usefull when you want to understand how your code will flow between branches and the merge relationships.

Answer (score 34):

Just clarifying some terminology in James Reed's answer.

**re: "I don't consider the source a branch"**

In a biological tree, the *Trunk* is not called a *Branch*.

In computer terminology, both sides of a `branching relationship` are called `Branches`.  It is only the visualization that chooses to show the original *branch* as a *trunk* like on a biological tree. (Because the Visualization tools are written by and for us humans who prefer to *think* of the [1st original] `source branch` as the *Trunk* of a biological tree, and the `target branch` as the *Branch* off of the *Trunk*.)

In TFS 2008 terminology, a `Branch` is a `Folder` that has a `branching relationship` to another `Folder`.  Internally they are both `folder objects`.

In TFS (since 2010) terminology, a `Branch` is an internal `branch object` that is [very much like] a `folder object` with lots of extra metadata (and a different icon).

**re: why is the default to convert your source folder to a branch?**

In almost all normal circumstances, when you want to **branch the Trunk**, you want the source `Folder` [object] converted to be a `Branch` [object] so that you have all that extra metadata, which allows the extra Visualizations and Manipulations that are not available with a mere `Folder` [object].

A restriction is that a `Branch` [object] may not contain another `Branch` [object], but a `Branch` [object] can contain a `Folder` [object].  So sometimes, in a complex project, you may need to convert a `Branch` [object] back into a `Folder` [object] so you can put it inside a higher `Branch` [object].

To do that, use the menu command **File / Source Control / Branching and Merging / Convert to Folder**.  (: It is not on the right-click Context menu because it is needed so rarely. :)

If in managing your total project, you find you need/want to convert a `Folder` to a `Branch` (without yet creating a `branching relationship` by using the normal `Branch` command), use the menu command **File / Source Control / Branching and Merging / Convert to Branch**.

Comment: Very helpfull for someone who is comming from SVN. Seems like I must convert Main branch back to folder then divide individual projects into separate Main branches. Doesn't matter why I must do it, but you made my day easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To extend the James Reed answer.
According to Microsoft documentation on TFS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=tfs-2017#see-also):

you have a two major advantages of "Branch" over a "Folder":

1. Ability to view your branch hierarchy
2. Ability to track your changesets

> Branch a folder or file
>
> > Although you can branch a folder or file
> >     directly, we recommend that you avoid it. Otherwise, you will not be
> >     able to view your branch hierarchy or track your changesets.