# TFS > Branching: Converting Source Folder To Branch

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

TFS: What are the consequences of converting a source folder to a branch?

I want to create a branch from a folder in which we have our source code and I see the following option in "Branch" dialog in VisualStudio:

"Immediately convert source folder to branch (enables visualizations)"

Do I loose any information (e.g. file history etc.).

Are there any disadvantages to do it?

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Lerner.For.Ever

Comment: Also what are advantages of converting a source folder to a branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915808/folder-converted-to-branch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The release of Team Foundation Server 2010 began a **distinction** between branches and folders. The following illustration shows the top-level of the  folder structure in Source Control Explorer：

[image]

> As the illustration shows, you can still **use folders to organize
>   branches** within a team project's version control hierarchy. However,
>   folders and branches have a **different appearance** and **different
>   capabilities**. When you right-click a folder or branch and click
>   Properties, you display **different information** and **different
>   functionality**.
>
> When you **perform branch operations**, branches have important
>   advantages over folders. Branches support version control features
>   that provide extra visibility into your branch structure and into
>   where your changesets have merged. (For more information, see these
>   wonderful links: [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/))

Although you can still branch and merge among folders, **the best practice for your team is to branch and merge only among branches**.

Above points are all related to the difference in TFS and VS, something about Trunk and main, you could take a look at the answer from *Jesse Chisholm* in [Folder converted to branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915808/folder-converted-to-branch)